# How do I store certain values in a JSON hash in a new array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby, hash

In Ruby on Rails, I have managed to make an API request to receive a JSON response. I would like to iterate through the hash response and create a new array containing just the values of the `address` keys.

No code is included in this post because only the JSON response itself is needed to answer my question (my code simply consists of my API request). Here is the JSON response: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/qHFJKqbz)

In terms of what it should look like, it should be an array like so: ["1577 rue des Achillées","1549 rue des Achillées", etc.].

Comment: Please do not link to external sites that host your code. If you have code that is relevant to your question then you must include it directly in your question. I cannot visit pastebin from this location, making it impossible even to attempt to answer.

Comment: JSON is code & is the only information related to your question that is required to answer it. Please read [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ("*copy the code into the question itself*"). Also read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- is the only way to answer your question by including a 2102 line JSON snippet? Or can your question be answered just the same if you include just one or two elements from the array? Also read [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help); your code block will scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got what you have and what you want: your routes receives a JSON array and you want to return a new JSON with just the fields "address" of the input array. I'd do something like

```
def your_action
  render json: params[:your_json_array].map { |item| item[:address] }
end
```

or if you want to be more explicit

```
def your_action
  addresses = params[:your_json_array].map { |item| item[:address] }
  render json: addresses
end
```